# V$SQLAREA table contains SQL_FULLTEXT, how to find the source of the SQL in SQL_FULLTEXT

Tags: oracle, plsql

V$SQLAREA table contains SQL_FULLTEXT column, How do I find the actual source of the SQL, specifically if the SQL is a part of PL/SQL code, how to know that the SQL is part of which procedure?

Answer (score 3):

Check PROGRAM_ID and PROGRAM_LINE# which point to the object ID of the PLSQL program, which can be obtained by querying USER_OBJECTS.  The LINE# is ... as the name suggests, the line in the PLSQL module.

There is a full example of that process here

https://connor-mcdonald.com/2016/01/20/problematic-sql-plsql-is-your-friend/